# Maunal Navigation in Angular 6

Tags: angular, routes, communication

How can I redirect to other component in Angular 6 on the result of some function?

```
    Login(){

        console.log(this.LoginModel);
         this.userService.LoginUser(this.LoginModel).subscribe(
           result =>{
             if(result == null)
                console.log("Loged in successfully"); 
                /// here i want to go to dashboard component (router with path dashboard)               
           },
           error =>{
             console.log("Login - error");
           }

         );
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Inject the router service in your constructor.

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

constructor(
    private _router: Router
) {

}

goSomewhere() {
    this._router.navigate(['url']);
}
```